# Web service client can't find endpoint of web service

Tags: c#, windows, wcf, service, web

I have call to web service from windows service. Web service is referenced and all compiles with no errors and warnings. When I call method from web service I receive error which is shown below:

```
    Nie można odnaleźć elementu punktu końcowego o nazwie „WSHttpBinding_IWebService” i kontrakcie „RemoteServiceLancerto.IWebService” w sekcji konfiguracji klienta ServiceModel. Może to być spowodowane tym, że nie znaleziono pliku konfiguracji dla używanej aplikacji lub tym, że w elemencie klienta nie znaleziono elementu punktu końcowego pasującego do tej nazwy.
   w System.ServiceModel.Description.ConfigLoader.LoadChannelBehaviors(ServiceEndpoint serviceEndpoint, String configurationName)
   w System.ServiceModel.ChannelFactory.ApplyConfiguration(String configurationName, Configuration configuration)
   w System.ServiceModel.ChannelFactory.ApplyConfiguration(String configurationName)
   w System.ServiceModel.ChannelFactory.InitializeEndpoint(String configurationName, EndpointAddress address)
   w System.ServiceModel.ChannelFactory`1..ctor(String endpointConfigurationName, EndpointAddress remoteAddress)
   w System.ServiceModel.ConfigurationEndpointTrait`1.CreateSimplexFactory()
   w System.ServiceModel.ConfigurationEndpointTrait`1.CreateChannelFactory()
   w System.ServiceModel.ClientBase`1.CreateChannelFactoryRef(EndpointTrait`1 endpointTrait)
   w System.ServiceModel.ClientBase`1.InitializeChannelFactoryRef()
   w System.ServiceModel.ClientBase`1..ctor(String endpointConfigurationName, String remoteAddress)
   w CreativiumCounterService.DatabaseSync.getWebService() w d:\Projekty\Liczniki\CreativiumCounterService\DatabaseSync.cs:wiersz 144
   w CreativiumCounterService.DatabaseSync..ctor() w d:\Projekty\Liczniki\CreativiumCounterService\DatabaseSync.cs:wiersz 30
   w CreativiumCounterService.DatabaseSync.get_Instance() w d:\Projekty\Liczniki\CreativiumCounterService\DatabaseSync.cs:wiersz 49
   w CreativiumCounterService.CounterService.syncronizerWorker(Object sender, ElapsedEventArgs e) w d:\Projekty\Liczniki\CreativiumCounterService\CreativiumCounterService.cs:wiersz 0
```

You may want to see my client's(windows service) app.config so I show below;

```
<bindings>
  <wsHttpBinding>
    <binding name="WSHttpBinding_IWebService">
      <security mode="TransportWithMessageCredential">
        <transport clientCredentialType="None" />
        <message clientCredentialType="UserName" />
      </security>

    </binding>
  </wsHttpBinding>
</bindings>
<client>
  <endpoint address="https://domain.domain.com/Service/Service.svc"
    binding="wsHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="WSHttpBinding_IWebService"
    contract="RemoteServiceLancerto.IWebService" name="WSHttpBinding_IWebService" />
</client>

<behaviors>
  <serviceBehaviors>
    <behavior>
      <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="True"/>
      <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="True"/>

    </behavior>
  </serviceBehaviors>
</behaviors>
```

Certainly this is just a part of my config (web service part) with changed web service address.

Below is my method to get web service (which is referenced as RSL):

```
public RSL.WebServiceClient getWebService()
        {
            PreciousData details = PreciousData.deserialize();
            ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback = new RemoteCertificateValidationCallback(IgnoreCertificateErrorHandler);
            String ConnectionString = details.getWebServiceConnectionString();

            RSL.WebServiceClient client = new RemoteServiceLancerto.WebServiceClient("WSHttpBinding_IWebService", ConnectionString);

            client.ClientCredentials.UserName.UserName = details.getWebServiceLogin();
            client.ClientCredentials.UserName.Password = details.getWebServicePassword();


client.ClientCredentials.ServiceCertificate.Authentication.CertificateValidationMode = X509CertificateValidationMode.None;
            return client;
        }
```

At the moment I have no certificate validation in IgnoreCertificateErrorHandler but I show it below:

```
 public bool IgnoreCertificateErrorHandler(object sender, System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Certificate certificate,
            System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Chain chain, SslPolicyErrors sslPolicyErrors)
        {
            return true;
        }
```

In addition if I reference web service in casual WinForms app and then I use same code to call out methods from web service then it works. If more details is needed I can provide it. I must mention that web service was tested before troubles start after moving to web service. I've almost forgot. I call web service from System.Timers.Timer elapsed event.

Comment: will please mention error text?? "Nie można odnaleźć elementu punktu końcowego o nazwie"  what is this?

Comment: This is "Can't find endpoint with name"

Answer (score 1):

I found that solution presented here (second answer):
https://stackoverflow.com//questions/3703844/consume-a-soap-web-service-without-relying-on-the-app-config solves my problem because I create object in code. I wish I could find answer why it won't read app.config to automatically create  `WSHttpBinding`?